# Find out what kills a process

Tags: windows-10, process

I'm trying to run a game but the main process is dying after a few seconds and I think it is getting killed by some AV or some other program. I can't debug it with a debuger like OllyDbg, because the game loads Anti-Cheat-Software which detects the debugger.

Is there a way to find out what (program) kills my process?